# every TableView Cell updated instead of just one that is clicked.

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two Buttons (like/dislike) that works like thumbs up and down voting system style. When I click on the button though, every cell gets updated. Is there a way to solve this so that only the one that gets clicked updated?

Also, How do I reload the cell so that I don't have to pull to refresh to update the value of the button.setTitle value?

Here is my code:

```
PFTableViewCell:

class UserFeedCell: PFTableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dislikeButton: UIButton!


var vote: Int = 0 // initialize to user's existing vote, retrieved from the server
var likeCount: Int = 0 // initialize to existing like count, retrieved from the server
var dislikeCount: Int = 0 // initialize to existing dislike count, retrieved from the server

@IBAction func dislikeButton(sender: UIButton) {
buttonWasClickedForVote(-1)
print(likeCount)
print(dislikeCount)
```

}

```
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {
buttonWasClickedForVote(1)
print(likeCount)
print(dislikeCount)
```

}

```
private func buttonWasClickedForVote(buttonVote: Int) {
if buttonVote == vote {
    // User wants to undo her existing vote.
    applyChange(-1, toCountForVote: vote)
    vote = 0
}

else {
    // User wants to force vote to toggledVote.
    // Undo current vote, if any.
    applyChange(-1, toCountForVote: vote)

    // Apply new vote.
    vote = buttonVote
    applyChange(1, toCountForVote: vote)
}
```

}

```
private func applyChange(change: Int, toCountForVote vote: Int ) {
if vote == -1 { dislikeCount += change }
else if vote == 1 { likeCount += change }
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell" // your cell identifier name in storyboard 
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PFTableViewCell
cell.likeButton.selected = vote == 1
cell.dislikeButton.selected = vote == -1
cell.likeButton.titleLabel!.text = "\(likeCount)"
cell.dislikeButton.titleLabel!.text = "\(dislikeCount)"
return cell
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with delegate mechanism

Create `protocol` for your action:

```
 protocol LikeProtocol {
        func likeOrDislikeActionAtRow(row: Int)
    }
```

Make your `TableViewController` class confirm this protocol:

```
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController, LikeProtocol {
    ...
    func likeOrDislikeActionAtRow(row: Int) {
        ...
        // Reload only you want cell
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Add to your `PFTableViewCell` delegate object with type on `protocol` and `row` variable:

```
var delegate: LikeProtocol?
var rowValue: Int?
```

Set delegate and row at your `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`:

```
cell.delegate = self
cell.row = indexPath.row
```

Call protocol method in your like and dislike actions:

```
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    ....
    delegate!.likeOrDislikeActionAtRow(row!)
    ....
}
```

Comment: @SeungHong At this case i don't understand how it works. Give more derails. You have 2 buttons 'outlet' in every cell, then why your buttons actions are in the 'ViewController'? Is user push button inside cell, or there are buttons outside the 'TableView' and user can push it?

Comment: It's looks very strange, can you share link to you project or to files that contain code of your cells and 'TableViewController'?