# IBAction updates every cell row in tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a table view cell and `UITableViewController`. I have two **IBOutlets** (like/dislike) in table view cell. I also have two **IBActions** in the TableViewController. When the **IBActions** are clicked, it updates every single cell in the table view. Here is my code:

Table View Controller:

```
class UserFeedTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
var shouldReloadOnAppear: Bool = true

// Votes: -1 for dislike, 1 for like, 0 for no vote
var vote: Int = 0 // initialize to user's existing vote, retrieved from the server
var likeCount: Int = 0 // initialize to existing like count, retrieved from the server
var dislikeCount: Int = 0 // initialize to existing dislike count, retrieved from the server

@IBAction func dislikeButton(sender: UIButton) {

buttonWasClickedForVote(-1)

self.tableView.reloadData()
print(likeCount)
print(dislikeCount)
```

}

```
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {

buttonWasClickedForVote(1)

self.tableView.reloadData()
print(likeCount)
print(dislikeCount)
```

}

```
private func buttonWasClickedForVote(buttonVote: Int) {
if buttonVote == vote {
    // User wants to undo her existing vote.
    applyChange(-1, toCountForVote: vote)
    vote = 0
}

else {
    // User wants to force vote to toggledVote.
    // Undo current vote, if any.
    applyChange(-1, toCountForVote: vote)

    // Apply new vote.
    vote = buttonVote
    applyChange(1, toCountForVote: vote)
}
```

}

```
private func applyChange(change: Int, toCountForVote vote: Int ) {
if vote == -1 { dislikeCount += change }
else if vote == 1 { likeCount += change }
```

}

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
let CellIdentifier = "Cell"

    var cell: UserFeedCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UserFeedCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UserFeedCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)

    }

    if object != nil {
        cell!.likeButton.selected = vote == 1

        cell!.dislikeButton.selected = vote == -1
        cell!.likeButton.setTitle("\(likeCount)", forState: .Normal)
        cell!.dislikeButton.setTitle("\(dislikeCount)", forState: .Normal)

    }

return cell
}
```

Table View Cell:

```
class UserFeedCell: PFTableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var dislikeButton: UIButton!

var post: PFObject? {
 didSet{   
  }
```

}
}

Comment: Please describe your problem more in detail, its not totally clear whats exactly your problem. Add it inside the post, so people see it immediately when the start reading your post!

Comment: so when I press on the like/dislike button, the title and button state changes for every cell. I want it so that it only changes for the one that user presses.

Comment: It is third version of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421957/every-tableview-cell-updated-instead-of-just-one-that-is-clicked/33422672#33422672 and it is not unclear, that two buttons, that separate from the cells, while pressed have to  update the data at particular cell. If you have only 2 buttons, is the cell selected on the press moment or are there another two buttons on every single cell by pressing it generate action form two global buttons in yor `TableViewController`?

Comment: please check my code. I only have two buttons. When I press any of the buttons, every single button state, title get updated.

Comment: likeCount and dislikeCount are managed by your view controller class, UserFeedTableViewController. When you click a button, you update one of those values, then call reloadData. This will reload the the whole table using the new updated values for likeCount/dislikeCount, so all the cells will have the new values. Is this your intention? or do you intend to have a separate likeCount/dislikeCount that is specific to the the cell?

Comment: reloading the whole tableview is my intention. can you post a sample answer please? Thanks Jimmy!

Comment: Your intention is to reload the whole table, so each cell in the table reloads with the new values likeCount and dislikeCount. reloadData reloads every cell. You are setting the button titles with cell!.likeButton.setTitle("\(likeCount)", forState: .Normal) in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Every cell will have the same title on its likeButton because every cell sets the title using the value of likeCount.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood you. My intention is just to update that buttons that users click on. Not every single cell. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I don't know your data model. Whatever it is that you are liking or disliking needs to have its own like/dislike count associated with it. If you have 20 items, you need a like and a dislike for each of the 20 items. Right now you are sharing a single instance of likeCount and dislikeCount among all cells.